# How to make iOS Safari saves password for basic authentication website?

Tags: ios, security, https, safari, basic-authentication

I'm currently developing a website using **basic authentication over https**

Some customers using **iOS Safari** have complained that Safari does not ask to save password.

it seems that iOS Safari asks to save password only when the website implements a **form based authentication**.

I don't want to install a third party browser or app on all devices to solve this problem.

So, is there any way to force iOS Safari to save password for basic authentication websites ?

Answer (score 7):

According to answer on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45285/is-there-a-way-to-have-ios-remember-passwords-to-http-authenticated-sites), you are not able to save Http Basic Auth credentials with Safari on IOS. If the security level of your service permits, you can save the credentials to a bookmark by adding credentials to it like so:

```
https://username:password@url.tldn/path
```

---

Comment: This is not a good solution for several reasons. The URL may be read by other users on the same machine. The URL may be logged in some non-secure place on the remote machine. Your browser history would then also contain a copy of your password.

Comment: @PEC 's comment is incorrect. The browser handles the password the same way as when you input it manually. It will not be stored in the history and will not be sent to the server as a URL.

It will still be stored unencrypted in the bookmark, of course.

Comment: Incidentally, security concerns aside, this doesn’t appear to work. Even providing user and password, the modal dialog pops up, with neither filled out. Which basically makes sites with Ajax requests unusable (you’ll be doing a _lot_ of typing). But, I’ve found (I think) that iCab appears to save credentials within the session.

Comment: @SörenKuklau "Which basically makes sites with Ajax requests unusable" - If you are using AJAX requests then you should probably be sending the `Authorization` HTTP request header as part of every request (not in the URL), instead of letting the user manually authenticate. (?)

Comment: I don't know that AJAX is what's going on; all I know is Safari puts up a lot of HTTP authentication prompts (despite credentials being correct), and other browsers don't.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15, Settings > Passwords allows adding new entries by hand. You can fill in the website URL and the credentials here. The next time the basic auth dialog shows up, it will not, unfortunately, be pre-filled, but you will be presented with the Passwords button in your on-screen keyboards once you focus either of the username / password fields and from there you can pick the credentials. It's not completely straight-forward, but it is the best option I found, especially because some websites do not support reading the username and password from the URL, only from the HTTP header, so the trick with the bookmark with the credentials in it doesn't work everywhere.